# ReferenceError: Can't find variable error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var callPage = function(){
        $.post('/pageToCall.php');
    };

    setInterval('callPage()', 60000);
});
```

and it gives me the error `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: callPage`. Why?

Comment: what you expect in callpage. function returns nothing it looks!

Comment: @zod: the return value of callPage (or lack thereof) is irrelevant. What's relevant is probably the type of the first parameter of setInterval, as Bryan suggested.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try `setInterval(callPage, 60000);`.

If you pass a string to `setInterval`, then this string is evaluated in *global scope*. The problem is that `callPage` is *local* to the `ready` callback, it is not global.

There is hardly ever a reason to pass a string to `setInterval` (`setTimeout`). Always pass a function (to avoid exactly this kind of errors).

Comment: yea...  you're passing a reference to a function. Not a String.

Comment: @Felix Kling I refuse to gain reputation points from your answer, actually I would like to vote for your explanation :)

Comment: @Darhazer: Well, I hope you at least don't loose any through that... It was totally fine for me, I already have enough reputation points ;) Your answer was correct and I didn't see a need to provide my own just to explain it... anyway what's done is done.

Comment: @Felix Kling I've already earned the maximum daily reputation, so I'm not loosing anything either. But the purpose of SO is to educate readers, and not just giving a working code, so thank you for adding the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect it's because callPage is a variable scoped to the anonymous function you're creating in the document.ready event. If you move the callPage definition outside that, does it work?

Answer (score 1):

```js
function callPage()
{
    $.post('/pageToCall.php');
};

$(document).ready(function()
{
    setInterval('callPage()', 60000);
});
```

It happens because callPage's scope is the anonymous function